# Use ImmediateRequeueMessageRecoverer in Spring Integration for AMQP?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-amqp

We've noticed that when erroneous messages are received to a Spring Integration Endpoint (from RabbitMQ) they are not retried. If there's a problem in our business code (i.e. the "service method" that receives the messages) so that it throws an exception, retries happen as they are supposed to.

This is our configuration:

```java
var myService = ...
IntegrationFlows.from(Amqp.inboundAdapter(connectionFactory, queueName)
                .id(integrationFlowId)
                .autoStartup(autoStartup)
                .configureContainer(c -> c.acknowledgeMode(MANUAL)
                        .prefetchCount(10)
                        .concurrentConsumers(1)
                        .maxConcurrentConsumers(3))
                .messageConverter(messageConverter))
                .aggregate(...)
                .handle(myService, "myMethod", e -> e.advice(myAdvice()))
                .get();
```

The `myAdvice`method is implemented like this:

```
ExponentialBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new ExponentialBackOffPolicy();
backOffPolicy.setInitialInterval(200L);
backOffPolicy.setMultiplier(2);
backOffPolicy.setMaxInterval(5000L);

RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy((new SimpleRetryPolicy(MAX_VALUE)));
retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy);
retryTemplate.registerListener(new RetryListenerSupport() {
    @Override
    public <T, E extends Throwable> void onError(RetryContext ctx, RetryCallback<T, E> callback, Throwable e) {
        log.error("Caught {} due to {} (count = {})", e.getClass().getSimpleName(), e.getMessage(), ctx.getRetryCount(), e);
    }
});
StatelessRetryOperationsInterceptorFactoryBean bean = new StatelessRetryOperationsInterceptorFactoryBean();
bean.setRetryOperations(retryTemplate);
bean.setMessageRecoverer(new ImmediateRequeueMessageRecoverer());
return bean.getObject();
```

The problem is that if we, for example, publish a message (such as `{ "yo" : "MTV Raps" }`) that the `org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConverter` cannot convert into a DTO, the message is not retried:

```
[my-service-97c696799-6xs26] org.springframework.amqp.AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException: Error Handler converted exception to fatal
[my-service-97c696799-6xs26]    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler.handleError(ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler.java:146)
[my-service-97c696799-6xs26]    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeErrorHandler(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1436)
[my-service-97c696799-6xs26]    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.handleListenerException(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1720)
[my-service-97c696799-6xs26]    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1495)
[my-service-97c696799-6xs26]    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:967)
[my-service-97c696799-6xs26]    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:913)
[my-service-97c696799-6xs26]    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1600(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:83)
[my-service-97c696799-6xs26]    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.mainLoop(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1288)
[my-service-97c696799-6xs26]    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1194)
[my-service-97c696799-6xs26]    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:831)
[my-service-97c696799-6xs26] Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener threw exception
[my-service-97c696799-6xs26]    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.wrapToListenerExecutionFailedExceptionIfNeeded(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1746)
[my-service-97c696799-6xs26]    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1636)
[my-service-97c696799-6xs26]    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.actualInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1551)
[my-service-97c696799-6xs26]    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1539)
[my-service-97c696799-6xs26]    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1530)
[my-service-97c696799-6xs26]    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1474)
[my-service-97c696799-6xs26]    ... 6 common frames omitted
[my-service-97c696799-6xs26] Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.support.converter.MessageConversionException: Don't know how to convert (Body:'{ "yo" : "MTV Raps" }' MessageProperties [headers={content_type=application/json}, contentType=application/json, contentLength=0, receivedDeliveryMode=NON_PERSISTENT, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=, receivedRoutingKey=myservice.routingkey, deliveryTag=1, consumerTag=amq.ctag-9De2w0uuQxnve_9k6HZ7tw, consumerQueue=myservice.myqueue]) to an object because no event type was found
[my-service-97c696799-6xs26]    at com.mycompany.RabbitMQEventMessageConverter.fromMessage(RabbitMQEventMessageConverter.java:47)
[my-service-97c696799-6xs26]    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.convertPayload(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:361)
[my-service-97c696799-6xs26]    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.createMessageFromAmqp(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:342)
[my-service-97c696799-6xs26]    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.createAndSend(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:334)
[my-service-97c696799-6xs26]    at org.springframework.integration.amqp.inbound.AmqpInboundChannelAdapter$Listener.onMessage(AmqpInboundChannelAdapter.java:299)
[my-service-97c696799-6xs26]    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1632)
[my-service-97c696799-6xs26]    ... 10 common frames omitted
```

It seems like the `ImmediateRequeueMessageRecoverer` specified in the `myAdvice()` method is not used, rather the default `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException` is used. The reason is most likely, in my mind, that the `myAdvice()` method has not been called by the Spring infrastructure yet. I've tried finding a way to switch the message recoverer in `configureContainer`, but I cannot seem to find a way to do so.

Does anyone know how I can re-queue/retry messages that fail *before* the "service method" is invoked by spring integration?

We're using Spring Integration 5.4.6 and Spring Boot 2.4.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conversion is performed before a message is created.

Conversion errors are generally considered to be fatal - there is no point in retrying it because it will fail again.

Add an `.errorChannel` to the inbound adapter; its downstream flow will get an `ErrorMessage` for conversion errors.

However, it will also get error messages from the downstream flow too, so you will have to handle all error types there.

**EDIT**

You can add an error channel and handle the conversion exception on its flow. Bear in mind, though, that the message will be redelivered over and over again, with no delay.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So67801807Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So67801807Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow flow(ConnectionFactory cf) {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(Amqp.inboundAdapter(cf, "foo")
                    .messageConverter(new MC())
                    .errorChannel("errors"))
                .handle(...)
                .get();
    }

    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow errorFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from("errors")
                .handle(msg -> {
                    if (((ErrorMessage) msg).getPayload().getCause() instanceof MessageConversionException) {
                        throw new ImmediateRequeueAmqpException("Requeuing due to conversion");
                    }
                    else {
                        // handle some other exception thrown by the downstream flow
                    }
                })
                .get();
    }

}

class MC implements MessageConverter {

    @Override
    public Message toMessage(Object object, MessageProperties messageProperties) throws MessageConversionException {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object fromMessage(Message message) throws MessageConversionException {
        throw new MessageConversionException("test");
    }

}
```

Or you can add a custom error handler to the container. The default error handler considers conversion exceptions to be fatal.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#exception-handling

Comment: Just so that I understand it correctly, there's no way to just requeue the message? You're right that we cannot process this message right now, but for us, this error happens when one system (A) publishes an updated version of the message that (B) is interested in, but it needs to be updated before it can read it properly. I.e. we've forgot to update B before A publishes the updated message. What we want to do is then to let B requeue the message so that we can update it to support the new message, then redeploy. Then the message can be processed again correctly. We don't want to lose the msg!

Comment: When there is no `.errorChannel` the `MessageConversionException` is thrown to the container; the container's default `ErrorHandler` (a `ConditionalRejectingErrorHandler`) considers conversion exceptions as fatal and throws an `AmqpRejectAndDontRequeue` exception. You can either change the container's `ErrorHandler` by configuring the `FatalExceptionStrategy`, or you can add logic to the error channel flow. I will edit my answer to show an example of the latter. Bear in mind though, that the message will be redelivered over and over until the problem is fixed.